# Is it possible to disable OS information in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, operating-system, enumeration

ElasticSearch API can retrieve OS details with this API request:

```
http://IP:9200/_nodes/os/
```

Is there a way to disable this feature?

thx

Comment: Not that I know of. What's the issue with that info?

Comment: the problem is that it give really precise informations about OS and jvm version that could lead to a further compromision

Comment: To whom? Is your cluster open to the outside world?

Comment: It could happen sometimes you know in some misconfigurated environnement

Comment: So, perhaps, you should make sure that this doesn't happen :-) Hiding OS info won't save you from that.

Comment: yep sure but that is not the anwser to the question ;)